How make WSDL-file with (WSSE) WS-security
I need to get the following (expected) xml request from a WSDL file (attention to wsu + wsse identifiers + PasswordText) right after insertion from wsdl (without third-party injections)
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ftf="http://mycompany.com"> 
    <soapenv:Header> 
        <wsse:Security 
          soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" 
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken> 
                <wsse:Username>?</wsse:Username> 
                <wsse:Password Type="?">mypassword</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken> 
        </wsse:Security> 
    </soapenv:Header> 
    <soapenv:Body> 
        <ftf:DsOfferedRateDeleteReq>
            <!--Optional:--> 
            <ftf:OfferedRateID>?</ftf:OfferedRateID> 
        </ftf:DsOfferedRateDeleteReq> 
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>

Current xml request from my current wsdl
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sup="http://mycompany.com" xmlns:req="http://mycompany.com/type/request">   
    <soapenv:Header> 
        <sup:Security> 
            <UsernameToken> 
                <Username>?</Username> 
                <Password>?</Password> 
            </UsernameToken> 
        </sup:Security> 
    </soapenv:Header> 
    <soapenv:Body> 
        <req:DsOfferedRateDeleteReq> 
            <!--Optional:--> 
            <req:OfferedRateID>?</req:OfferedRateID> 
        </req:DsOfferedRateDeleteReq> 
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>

At the moment, I can only do this wsdl:
(see my answer below, because stackoverflow didn't let me post so much code...)

Do you have any ideas how to finish the wsdl so that the expected response is formed?

My current wsdl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns:wsse="http://support.mycompany.com"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:tns="http://support.mycompany.com"
     xmlns:ftf="http://service.mycompany.com"
     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:request="http://support.mycompany.com/type/request"
     xmlns:response="http://support.mycompany.com/type/response"

     targetNamespace="http://support.mycompany.com" name="FTFWS">

     <types>

         <xsd:schema
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
             targetNamespace="http://support.mycompany.com">
             <xsd:complexType name="SecurityHeader">
                 <xsd:sequence>
                     <xsd:element name="UsernameToken">
                         <xsd:complexType>
                             <xsd:sequence>
                                 <xsd:element name="Username"
type="xsd:string"/>
                                 <xsd:element name="Password"
type="xsd:string"/>
                             </xsd:sequence>
                         </xsd:complexType>
                     </xsd:element>
                 </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:complexType>
             <xsd:element name="Security" type="wsse:SecurityHeader"/>
         </xsd:schema>

         <xsd:schema
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:tns="http://support.mycompany.com"
             targetNamespace="http://support.mycompany.com"
             elementFormDefault="qualified">

             <complexType name="ContextData">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="fromSystem"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="toSystem"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="sessionId"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:long" name="processId"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:language" name="locale"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:ContextData" name="ContextData" />

             <complexType name="OperationFault">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="faultCode"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="faultMessage"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:OperationFault" name="OperationFault" />

             <complexType name="DSCALLFAULT">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:int" name="faultcode"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="faultmessage"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:DSCALLFAULT" name="DSCALLFAULT" />

             <complexType name="DSCALLRESPONSE">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="commandresult"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:DSCALLRESPONSE" name="DSCALLRESPONSE" />

             <complexType name="DSCALL">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="commandtext"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="commanddata"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:ContextData" name="contextdata"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:DSCALL" name="DSCALL" />

             <complexType name="DSCALLASYNC">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="commandtext"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="commanddata"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:ContextData" name="contextdata"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:DSCALLASYNC" name="DSCALLASYNC" />

             <complexType name="Admmoduleinfo">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="tns:ContextData" name="ContextData"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:Admmoduleinfo" name="Admmoduleinfo" />

             <complexType name="AdmmoduleinfoRes">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="PACKAGESYSNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="PACKAGENAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="PACKAGEVERSION"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="EXTINTEGRATION"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="PACKAGESTATUS"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="PACKAGEMONITOR"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:Right" name="PACKAGERIGHTS"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                     <element type="tns:Group" name="PACKAGEGROUPS"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                     <element type="tns:Role" name="PACKAGEROLES"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                     <element type="tns:PackageDescription"
name="PACKAGEDESCRIPTION" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:AdmmoduleinfoRes" name="AdmmoduleinfoRes" />

             <complexType name="RoleRightFilter">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="SYSNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OPERATION"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:anyType" name="VALUES"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:RoleRightFilter" name="RoleRightFilter" />

             <complexType name="RoleRight">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="RIGHTSYSNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:RoleRightFilter" name="FILTERS"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:RoleRight" name="RoleRight" />

             <complexType name="Role">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="ROLESYSNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="ROLENAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="DESCRIPTION"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:RoleRight" name="RIGHTS"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:Role" name="Role" />

             <complexType name="RightFilter">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="SYSNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OPERATION"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="DATASOURCEURL"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:RightFilter" name="RightFilter" />

             <complexType name="Right">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="RIGHTSYSNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="RIGHTNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="RIGHTPARENT"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:RightFilter" name="FILTERS"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:Right" name="Right" />

             <complexType name="GroupRightFilter">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="SYSNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OPERATION"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:anyType" name="VALUES"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:GroupRightFilter" name="GroupRightFilter" />

             <complexType name="GroupRight">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="RIGHTSYSNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:GroupRightFilter" name="FILTERS"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:GroupRight" name="GroupRight" />

             <complexType name="Group">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="GROUPNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="DESCRIPTION"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:Group" name="GROUPS"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                     <element type="tns:Right" name="RIGHTS"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:Group" name="Group" />

             <complexType name="Service">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="SVCALIAS"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="SVCDESC"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:Service" name="Service" />

             <complexType name="Module">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="MODULENAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="MODULEDESC"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:Module" name="Module" />

             <complexType name="ServiceMethod">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="METHODNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="METHODDESC"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="FINDER"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:Parameter" name="METHODPARAMSIN"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                     <element type="tns:Parameter"
name="METHODPARAMSOUT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:ServiceMethod" name="ServiceMethod" />

             <complexType name="Parameter">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="ATTRNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="ATTRDESC"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:Parameter" name="ATTRCHILD"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="ATTRTYPE"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="REQUIRED"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:Parameter" name="Parameter" />

             <complexType name="ObjOperation">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OPERNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OPERDESC"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OPERSMETHOD"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:ObjOperation" name="ObjOperation" />

             <complexType name="BObject">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OBJSYSNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OBJNAME"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OBJNAMELAT"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="OBJDESC"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:boolean" name="SUPPORTSCLS"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:boolean" name="SUPPORTSVER"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:boolean" name="SUPPORTSSTM"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:boolean" name="SUPPORTSADAT"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="tns:ObjOperation"
name="OBJOPERATIONS" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:BObject" name="BObject" />

             <complexType name="PackageDescription">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="tns:Module" name="BMODULE"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                     <element type="tns:Service" name="SERVICE"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                     <element type="tns:ServiceMethod"
name="SERVICEMETHODS" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                     <element type="tns:BObject" name="BOBJECTS"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:PackageDescription"
name="PackageDescription" />

             <complexType name="GetVersion">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="tns:ContextData" name="ContextData"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:GetVersion" name="GetVersion" />

             <complexType name="GetVersionRes">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="Project-Version"
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:GetVersionRes" name="GetVersionRes" />

             <complexType name="GetHealthInfo">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="tns:ContextData" name="ContextData"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:GetHealthInfo" name="GetHealthInfo" />

             <complexType name="GetHealthInfoRes">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="tns:HealthInfoElement" name="Result"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:GetHealthInfoRes" name="GetHealthInfoRes" />

             <complexType name="HealthInfoElement">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="key" minOccurs="0"
maxOccurs="1" />
                     <element type="xsd:int" name="value" minOccurs="0"
maxOccurs="1" />
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="tns:HealthInfoElement"
name="HealthInfoElement" />
         </xsd:schema>
         <xsd:schema
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:type="http://support.mycompany.com/type"

             targetNamespace="http://support.mycompany.com/type"
             elementFormDefault="qualified">

         </xsd:schema>
         <xsd:schema
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:request="http://support.mycompany.com/type/request"

             xmlns:type="http://support.mycompany.com/type"

targetNamespace="http://support.mycompany.com/type/request"
             elementFormDefault="qualified">
             <complexType name="DsOfferedRateDeleteReq">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:long" name="OfferedRateID"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="request:DsOfferedRateDeleteReq"
name="DsOfferedRateDeleteReq"/>

         </xsd:schema>
         <xsd:schema
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:response="http://support.mycompany.com/type/response"

             xmlns:type="http://support.mycompany.com/type"

targetNamespace="http://support.mycompany.com/type/response"
             elementFormDefault="qualified">
             <complexType name="DsOfferedRateDeleteRes">
                 <sequence>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="Status"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                     <element type="xsd:string" name="ReturnMsg"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                     <element type="xsd:long" name="ReturnCode"
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                 </sequence>
             </complexType>
             <element type="response:DsOfferedRateDeleteRes"
name="DsOfferedRateDeleteRes"/>

         </xsd:schema>

     </types>

     <message name="SecurityHeader">
         <part name="Security" element="wsse:Security"/>
     </message>

     <message name="fault">
         <part name="fault" element="tns:OperationFault"/>
     </message>

     <message name="DSCALLFAULT">
         <part name="DSCALLFAULT" element="tns:DSCALLFAULT"/>
     </message>

     <message name="DSCALL">
         <part name="request" element="tns:DSCALL"/>
     </message>

     <message name="DSCALLRESPONSE">
         <part name="commandresult" element="tns:DSCALLRESPONSE"/>
     </message>

     <message name="DSCALLASYNC">
         <part name="request" element="tns:DSCALLASYNC"/>
     </message>

     <message name="Admmoduleinfo">
         <part name="request" element="tns:Admmoduleinfo"/>
     </message>

     <message name="AdmmoduleinfoRes">
         <part name="response" element="tns:AdmmoduleinfoRes"/>
     </message>

     <message name="GetVersion">
         <part name="request" element="tns:GetVersion"/>
     </message>

     <message name="GetVersionRes">
         <part name="response" element="tns:GetVersionRes"/>
     </message>

     <message name="GetHealthInfo">
         <part name="request" element="tns:GetHealthInfo"/>
     </message>

     <message name="GetHealthInfoRes">
         <part name="response" element="tns:GetHealthInfoRes"/>
     </message>

     <message name="DsOfferedRateDeleteReq">
         <part name="request" element="request:DsOfferedRateDeleteReq"/>
     </message>
     <message name="DsOfferedRateDeleteRes">
         <part name="response" element="response:DsOfferedRateDeleteRes"/>
     </message>

     <portType name="FTFWSPORTTYPE">
         <operation name="DSCALL">
             <input message="tns:DSCALL" />
             <output message="tns:DSCALLRESPONSE" />
             <fault name="DSCALLFAULT" message="tns:DSCALLFAULT" />
         </operation>

         <operation name="DSCALLASYNC">
             <input message="tns:DSCALLASYNC" />
         </operation>

         <operation name="admModuleInfo">
             <input message="tns:Admmoduleinfo" />
             <output message="tns:AdmmoduleinfoRes" />
             <fault name="fault" message="tns:fault" />
         </operation>

         <operation name="getversion">
             <input message="tns:GetVersion" />
             <output message="tns:GetVersionRes" />
             <fault name="fault" message="tns:fault" />
         </operation>

         <operation name="getHealthInfo">
             <input message="tns:GetHealthInfo" />
             <output message="tns:GetHealthInfoRes" />
             <fault name="fault" message="tns:fault" />
         </operation>
         <operation name="dsOfferedRateDelete">
             <input message="tns:DsOfferedRateDeleteReq"/>
             <output message="tns:DsOfferedRateDeleteRes"/>
             <fault name="fault" message="tns:fault"/>
         </operation>

     </portType>
     <binding type="tns:FTFWSPORTTYPE" name="FTFWSBINDING">
         <soap:binding
             style="document"
             transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

         <operation name="DSCALL">
             <soap:operation
soapAction="http://support.mycompany.com/DSCALL" />
             <input>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </input>
             <output>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </output>
             <fault name="DSCALLFAULT">
                 <soap:fault use="literal" name="DSCALLFAULT" />
             </fault>
         </operation>

         <operation name="DSCALLASYNC">
             <soap:operation
soapAction="http://support.mycompany.com/DSCALLASYNC" />
             <input>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </input>
         </operation>

         <operation name="admModuleInfo">
             <soap:operation
soapAction="http://support.mycompany.com/admModuleInfo" />
             <input>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </input>
             <output>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </output>
             <fault name="fault">
                 <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault" />
             </fault>
         </operation>

         <operation name="getversion">
             <soap:operation
soapAction="http://support.mycompany.com/getversion" />
             <input>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </input>
             <output>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </output>
             <fault name="fault">
                 <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault" />
             </fault>
         </operation>

         <operation name="getHealthInfo">
             <soap:operation
soapAction="http://support.mycompany.com/getHealthInfo" />
             <input>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </input>
             <output>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </output>
             <fault name="fault">
                 <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault" />
             </fault>
         </operation>
         <operation name="dsOfferedRateDelete">
             <soap:operation
soapAction="http://support.mycompany.com/dsOfferedRateDelete" />
             <input>
                 <soap:header message="wsse:SecurityHeader"
part="Security" use="literal"/>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </input>
             <output>
                 <soap:body use="literal" />
             </output>
             <fault name="fault">
                 <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault" />
             </fault>
         </operation>

     </binding>
     <service name="FTFWSSERVICE">
         <port binding="tns:FTFWSBINDING" name="FTFWSPORT">
             <soap:address location="FTFWS" />
         </port>
     </service>
</definitions>



Go to ShowProject view -> WS-Security Configurations (tab) -> Outgoing WS-Security Configurations
Add a new configuration and then add a security type like PasswordText.
On the request, right click anywhere on <soapenv:Header> -> Outgoing WSS. Apply the created configuration there.

It can be done for all requests in a wsdl

Right click on service -> Show Interface viewer -> Service Endpoints (tab). Set the configured WSS on Outgoing WSS column for the service hostname entry (it might need to be created)


No, it is necessary that the header has already been filled in its final form with this WSS (like at first xml-example in post above) when receiving a request from the wsdl - without manipulation on the soapui side

@Avraam question says "make SoapUI generate..." so it's not clear what is needed. The second option should send the security header automatically-

Yes, I check in it that which query is generated from the wsdl - but OK, I'll delete this sentence so that it doesn't mislead
